# Generating CSV with JS adds an extra empty column

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm generating a CSV file from an array of data using JS.

My data before the download is this:

```
var csv =
"Date,valA,valB,valC,valD,AVG
2016-07-01 12:00,393917,211,38534,640,9.78%,
2016-07-01 01:00,342278,171,38131,547,11.14%,
2016-07-01 02:00,265238,168,29395,547,11.08%,";
```

Every line has a line break character in the end (`"\n"`).

I then add the mime type at the beginning of the string:

`csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;`,

and then encode & download:

```
data = encodeURI(csv);
link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', data);
link.setAttribute('download', filename);
link.click();
```

Everything works fine, but In the final file there is an empty column for some reason.

I've looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516919/generating-a-csv-with-javascript-works-but-i-am-getting-an-empty-trailing-column) but it is far too detailed. I think the solution here could be very simple.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the fact that every line had a comma (`","`) just before the line break caused the extra trailing column.

All I had to do is make sure my lines end just with a new line character.

The `csv` string should be:

```
var csv =
"Date,valA,valB,valC,valD,AVG
2016-07-01 12:00,393917,211,38534,640,9.78%
2016-07-01 01:00,342278,171,38131,547,11.14%
2016-07-01 02:00,265238,168,29395,547,11.08%";
```

(notice no trailing commas).